# mod_rewrite to dynamically send to sub-folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm a complete novice when it comes to htaccess. I've searched for my exact problem to no avail.. perhaps I did not even know what to search for, haha.
Goodness, the title of this question might not even be appropriate!

Here goes:

I need: 
https://www.example.com/1 (the 1 (one) at the end will be inserted by the user. So, it may be https://www.example.com/2057 for example. What ever the number at the end, I need it to go to:
https://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/1 (or what ever number is inserted.)

The closest I've come to is this:
RewriteRule ^/(.*) folder1/folder2/%1/index.php? [R,L]

However, this gives a VERY long example.com/folder1/folder2/folder/1/folder2.....for a LONG time.../1.php

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked at time of this posting. Hope it helps someone in the future.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)((?:A|L)[0-9]R[0-9]+[A-Z]?)$ 
https://www.mywebsite.com/folder/$2&login=$1 [L] 


RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)((?:A|L)[0-9]?)$ https:/www.mywebsite.com/folder/$2&login=$1 [L] 


RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ https:/www.mywebsite.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work in may case:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.examplesite.com/folder1/folder2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: don't feel this is right however. Getting SSL error now. When I check via: https://www.whynopadlock.com/ it throws http://www.examplesite.com/folder1/folder2/folder1/folder2/folder1/etcetc error for part of my script. So.... any help folks?